Terraform - Azure DataFactory Pipeline empty after runnig succsesfully
i'm currently testing Terraform to deploy Azure DataFactory Pipelines, i generate the Pipeline JSON File in the Azure DataFactory, then copy it into my Repo.
When running Terraform apply, it generates the Pipeline, but without the Copy Activity, i checked the logs but found nothing.
Terraform 
Azure DataFactory Pipeline JSON

While creating azure data factory pipeline using azurerm_data_factory_pipeline tf command, you should not give the entire piepline Json in the activities_json part of terraform code. You can copy only the activities array from the entire Json.

Copy only the highlighted part (as in below image) from the entire pipeline Json.


Save that and use it while creating adf pipeline.



Hi, i tried your soulution and it worked perfectly. Thank you !
